# 14.10 Wi-Fi connection problem

Tags: wireless, networking, intel-wireless

I recently started to experience problems with my Wi-Fi. I have Ubuntu 14.10 on a Dell Inspiron N4110. I recently began experiencing problems with my Wi-Fi. It would take randomly to  stop and disconnect (According to Google Chrome), even though it showed that it was connected (According to Ubuntu). It also showed me a message " (1) Creating object for path '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/6' failed in libnm-glib.  I am relatively new to Ubuntu and so if you want me to do Terminal, please also explain so that I may learn.

I saw this on another forum and so this may be of help to you. I ran "sudo lshw -C network" in Terminal and this is what I got.

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: ac:72:89:18:39:f9
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-24-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=10.0.0.7 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:49 memory:d1600000-d1601fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 14:fe:b5:bc:32:9f
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:46 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

Thanks.

Comment: @CharlesGreen Thanks for editing it. Copying and pasting messed it up.

Comment: No problem.  Copy, paste, hightlight pasted data and press ctrl+K to make it all into a code block...

Comment: Have you tried disabling ipv6?

Comment: I know Ip6 and ip4 have to do with Wi-Fi but that is all I know about them.

Comment: How do I disable it?

Comment: I'll type into a answer - it's a little complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try disabling ipv6, and see if this helps.  Ipv6 is a newer internet addressing protocol, and sometimes older hardware and software seem to get a little bunged up by it, for no apparent reason.

To disable Ipv6, open a terminal window (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and enter the following command

`sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf`

This will open an editor to the file `sysctl.conf`.  scroll to the end, and enter the lines

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Save the file by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, and exit by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>.  You can then force the load of the modified file by entering the command `sudo sysctl -p`

To revert to what you had before, edit the file again, removing the added lines, and reboot

Comment: It seems good for now but since the problem seems to be on and off, I will have to see over time. I don't need to reboot for it to activate, right?

Comment: If you did the `sudo sysctl -p` then it loaded the parameters and you do not have to reboot.

Comment: Thank you. Everything seems fine. I will just have to wait and see.

Comment: It seems that my Wi-Fi just gets super slow in the late evening (8 and up).

Comment: It seems that my WiFi works fine, even though I am not doing what you said. Perhaps my network was just being slow for a couple of days or so. Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: Um. WHY does this work? Seriously...

Comment: @Misogynist As to *why*, it is most likely that the local telecom has not fully upgraded to equipment that can handle the Ipv6 protocols effectively - I'm in a fairly rural area, running DSL that goes down about once an hour, on average.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go the **Edit connection** tab, a list will come up with all the connections.
2. Select the network connection you want to select.
3. Input **password**.

This works for me, although this is not a permanent solution.